# Docker image for sailsjs development on macosx hangs

Tags: node.js, macos, docker, sails.js

I have a docker image build on Arch Linux (sailsjs-dev) with node and sailsjs which I would like to use for development, mounting the app directory inside the container as follows:

```
docker run --rm --name testapp -p 1337:1337 -v $PWD:/app \
  sailsjs-dev sails lift
```

$PWD is the directory with the sails project.

This works fine on linux, but if I try to run it on macosx (with docker-machine) it hangs forever at the very beginning, with log level set on silly (in config/log.js):

```
info: Starting app...
```

There is no other output, this is all we get.

Note, the same docker image works perfectly also on mac with an express app. What could be peculiar of sail that causes the problem?

I can also add that on a mac docker uses a virtualbox instance named **[docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/)**.

Comment: can you share a gist with the full output? gist.github.com

Comment: in config/log.js  we add silly level for the log.

And this is the result: 


`gabrielem@ga testapp $ docker run --rm --name testapp -p 1337:1337 -v $PWD:/app positronicbrain/sailsjs-dev:2015-11-16 sails lift --verbose


info: Starting app...`

Comment: Hi @TravisWebb we solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solved it running npm install from within the docker container:

```
docker run --rm --name testapp -p 1337:1337 -ti -v $PWD:/app \
 sailsjs-dev /bin/bash

npm install --no-bin-links
```

`--no-bin-links` avoids the creation of symlinks.